# React: Anything wrong with using a simple function to A/B test in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am seeing a lot of libraries for this, but was wondering if I want to run a simple A/B test, is there any downside to using a randomizing function to select between 2 components to render rather than having a library do this for me with additional stuff I won't need?